# Dynamic load of xml files with localization in Android

Tags: android, localization

Is it possible to load xml-files with localization into APK? For example, device sends its local to server and gets file with all necessary strings, saves it into SD and uses it? As I understand, apk will always  look into res folder and we have no access to it after packing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason you couldn't implement your own localization mechanism that would use downloaded XML files. The resource mechanism, however, can't be expanded at runtime so everything would have to be in the initial APK.